# Serving different XML content on the same web

Tags: php, redirect

I don't know if this is the suitable place to ask this question, so I am sorry if I am doing it wrong. I think this is not a duplicate question. If it is, I am sorry too.

Currently, I have a web app which takes its content from a unique XML document. The URL is "http://webapp.com/"

The problem is that now I have to create a second version of the web which uses a new different XML document, so I have to put them different URLs, something like the following:

http://webapp.com/activities
http://webapp.com/stages

How can I have all my sources on just one directory on server-side (I suppose it's better to maintain, the resources are cached better, etc...) but with these 2 URLs pointing to the folder and making the PHP loades the XML depending on the URL?

I suppose I have to change the .htaccess file to redirect to that folder, but how can I tell what XML I must load? And the user must see on the search bar the URL he used, for example "http://webapp.com/activities"

Can anybody help me please?
Thanks for all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a .htaccess rule to redirect a URL like `http://webapp.com/{anything}` to `http://webapp.com/?q={anything}`. Then in your script you can write conditions based on `$_GET['q']` and load different XML. That is if I understand your question right.